# Trigger keyup event when tab is pressed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to imitate the behaviour of "Enter" key in my Code by using "Tab" key. I tried using "keydown" which gets the console.log printed but doesn't let me enter anything in the input field.
Here's my code.

**HTML File:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="text-area">
        <button id="myBtn" onclick="selectText()" >Select Text</button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript file:**

```
let input = document.getElementById('text-area');
let button = document.getElementById('myBtn');
input.addEventListener("keyup",e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.key=='Enter'){
        console.log("Enter is pressed");
        button.click();
    }
});



function selectText(){
    let input1 = document.getElementById('text-area');
    input1.focus();
    input1.select();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TAB key is a special key reserved for navigation between HTML elements. So to use it for anything beside navigation you need to intercept the `keydown` event for this key and call `preventDefault()` on it.

For example:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('text-area');
let button = document.getElementById('myBtn');
input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.key == 'Tab') {
    console.log("Enter/Tab is pressed");
    button.click();
  }
});

input.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.key == 'Tab') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

function selectText() {
  let input1 = document.getElementById('text-area');
  input1.focus();
  input1.select();
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input id="text-area">
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="selectText()">Select Text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** this answer is only related by Angular, not about javascript

In your case you can write simply

```
<input (keydown.tab)="selectText()">
```

And forget create an eventListener keydown.enter.

But answer to your question you can [dispathEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent). Some like(*)

```
<!--see how you create a template reference variable and pass
    to the function-->
<input #inputId (keydown.tab)="createEnterEvent(inputId)">

  createEnterEvent(el: HTMLInputElement) {
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{
      code: "Enter",
      key: "Enter",
      keyCode: 13
    });

    el.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

But this **not** make a "submit" of the form. Only is util if you has an keydown.enter event defined in your input

(*)NOTE about template reference variable. In Angular 13, when you pass as function you has the "HTMLElement", when you get using `@ViewChild` you get a elementRef and you should use yourVariable.nativeElement to get the htmlElement

Comment: I don't think the OP is using Angular, or at least it's not obvious from the question.

Comment: @JakubKotrs, true, sorry (I went from a question of Rudrashish in Angular and I supposed that de question was related about Angular too), thanks for the advise